safari browser on iphone 14 - textarea resizing not working
I have placed a textarea on a simple HTML Page. The textarea can be resized easily on desktop (from right bottom corner) but not on mobile phone. I want the same functionality on mobile. Here's a hosted page that you can check in iphone safari browser.


.padding-0 {
    padding: 0;
}
.padding-5 {
    padding: 5px;
}
.padding-10 {
    padding: 10px;
}
<form>
    <label for="text-area-0">Text area without padding:</label><br>
    <textarea id="text-area-0" class="padding-0" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

    <label for="text-area-5">Text area with padding 5px:</label><br>
    <textarea id="text-area-5" class="padding-5" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

    <label for="text-area-10">Text area with padding 10px:</label><br>
    <textarea id="text-area-10" class="padding-10" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
</form>



External demo: https://pciimapstage.essentialdemo.com/textarea.html
Please help me if I am missing something here.
